# Redirect page/subfolder to new domain url without changing url in browser

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have been looking for an answer this without any luck (searched everywhere)

Basically, I want to rewrite a page (subfolder) to a new domain without changing the url.

I've tried with no luck:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain/$1 [P]
```

I have had a look at the "duplicate" question and it doesn't answer.

It does not explain how to rewrite a page to a new domain without changing the url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 1):

Proxy Pass might be what you are looking for.
It will use the url that they connected to, and act as a proxy to the new url. They will still see the old url.

```
ProxyVia on
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off

ProxyPass /test http://newdomain/test
ProxyPassReverse /test http://newdomain/test
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ http://newdomain/$1 [P,L]

the above rule will redirect all /test/... to backend without modifying the browser URL

Comment: it gives me a 500 server error

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ 
http://newdomain/$1 [P,L] 
</IfModule>

Comment: in addition, i want to point out that /test/ is simple a static page and it's 1 url that needs redirection to a whole new domain without changing the url

Comment: I forgot to mention that [P] flag is not allowed in htaccess files. You need to put this rule in the main apache virtual host configuration file.

Comment: ive got it working but when it redirects to the new domain, the images break as it tries to look for the images on the old domain.